# problem in factor analyzing

Tags: factor-analysis

i am having problem with my data. 
i am doing a research and my data is a real data that means the meaning of my data is important, i am trying to run factor analyzing on my data set to minimize the number of my attributes as i have 160 attributes and only 22 row
the problem is most of my data the answers are 0 or 1 and when i am trying to run FA on it it gives me error that the column with all value zero is producing NA , and i am not sure if i want to change the values from 0 and 1 to 1 and 2 do i need to add 1 value too all my entries or it will make my date bias ? 
i will appreciate any help here 
thank you

Comment: If you have a column with constant values, here is no information in it no matter what you do. You may want to look into item response theory.

Comment: thank you i am going to read about it , and one other question i have related to factor analyzing .

Comment: imagine i am having 160 attributes and after running factor analyzing i ended up with 20 factor , for example my first factor cover 12 of my attributes, is there any way that i can see which attributes has the most significant weight on that factor ?

Comment: You should be able to infer this by inspecting the factor loadings. Larger the coefficient, the greater its contribution.